# Closing jQuery Ui Tabs

Tags: jquery-tabs

I have followed the instructions on the jQuery site to close jQuery tabs but its not working. below is my code snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.tabs.closable.min.js"></script>

var mainTab = $("#contentTab").tabs({closable: true});
$("#checkup").click(function(){

mainTab.tabs('add','checkup.php','CheckUp');
var newIndex = mainTab.tabs("length") - 1;
mainTab.tabs("select", newIndex);
});

$("#registration").click(function(){

mainTab.tabs('add','reception.php','Registration');
var newIndex = mainTab.tabs("length") - 1;
mainTab.tabs("select", newIndex);
```

Comment: i don't any code where you try to close the tab, and i can't find closable in the options in the offical link http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#options, and by close you mean remove it, or just open the new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [A Close Button for jQuery UI Tabs](https://github.com/andrewwatts/ui.tabs.closable) and working [demo](http://andrew.io/playpen/ui.tabs.closable/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
function closeTab(tabTitle) {
 $('ul li[role=tab] a').each(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  if ($('a',parent).text() == tabTitle) {
   $('span',parent).click();
  }
 });
}
```